# Spatial Clustering - associate cluster attribute (id) to the geometry that is part of the cluster

Tags: sql, cluster-analysis, postgis

I'm having certain issues into associate a clustered set of geometries with their own proprieties.

### Data

I've a table with a set of geometries,

```
buildings {
gid integer,
geom geometry(Multipoligon,4326)
}
```

And I've run the function [ST_ClusterWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterWithin.html) with a certain threshold over a the "*buildings*" table. 
From that cluster analysis, I got a table that named "clusters",

```
clusters {
cid Integer,
geom geometry(GeometryCollection,4326)
}
```

### Question

I would love to extract into a table all geometry with associated its own cluster information.

```
clustered_building {
gid Integer
cid Integer
geom geometry(Multipoligon,4326)
}

 gid |    cid     |       geom            |   
-----+------------+-----------------------+
  1  |     1      | multypoligon(...)     |
  2  |     1      | multypoligon(...)     |
  3  |     1      | multypoligon(...)     |
  4  |     2      | multypoligon(...)     |
  5  |     3      | multypoligon(...)     |
  6  |     3      | multypoligon(...)     |
```

### What I Did *(but does not work)*

I've been trying using the two function [ST_GeometryN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html) / [ST_NumGeometries](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumGeometries.html) parse each MultyGeometry and extract the information of the cluster with this query that is derived from one of the Standard Example of the ST_Geometry manual page.

```
INSERT INTO  clustered_building (cid, c_item , geom)
SELECT sel.cid, n, ST_GeometryN(sel.geom, n) as singlegeom
FROM ( SELECT cid, geom, ST_NumGeometries(geom) as num
       FROM clusters") AS sel
       CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,sel.num) n
WHERE n <= ST_NumGeometries(sel.geom);
```

The query, it takes few seconds if I force to use a series of 10.

```
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,10)
```

But it got stuck when I ask to generate a series according to the number of item in each GeometryCollection. 
And also, this query does not allow me to link the single geometry to his own features into the building table because I'm losing the "gid"

could someone please help me, 
thanks

Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have you data, but using some dummy values, where ids 1, 2 and 3 intersect and 4 and 5, you can do something like the following:

```
WITH 
  temp (id, geom) AS 
    (VALUES (1, ST_Buffer(ST_Makepoint(0, 0), 2)),
    (2, ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(1, 1), 2)),
    (3, ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(2, 2), 2)), 
    (4, ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(9, 9), 2)), 
    (5, ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(10, 10), 2))),
  clusters(geom) as 
    (SELECT 
        ST_Makevalid(
          ST_CollectionExtract(
              unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(geom)), 3)) 
      FROM temp
    )
 SELECT array_agg(temp.id), cl.geom 
   FROM clusters cl, temp 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(cl.geom, temp.geom) 
GROUP BY cl.geom;
```

If you wrap the final cl.geom is ST_AsText, you will see something like:

> {1,2,3}   | MULTIPOLYGON(((2.81905966523328 0.180940334766718,2.66293922460509 -0.111140466039203,2.4142135623731 -0.414213562373094,2.11114046603921 -0.662939224605089,1.81905966523328 -0.819059665233282,1.84775906502257 -0.765366864730179,1.96157056080646 -0.390180644032256,2 0,2 3.08780778723872e-16,2 0,2.39018064403226 0.0384294391935396,2.76536686473018 0.152240934977427,2.81905966523328 0.180940334766718))......
>
> {4,5}     | MULTIPOLYGON(((10.8190596652333 8.18094033476672,10.6629392246051 7.8888595339608,10.4142135623731 7.58578643762691,10.1111404660392 7.33706077539491,9.76536686473018 7.15224093497743,9.39018064403226 7.03842943919354,9 7,8.60981935596775 7.03842943919354,8.23463313526982 7.15224093497743,7.8888595339608 7.33706077539491,7.58578643762691 7.5857864376269,7.33706077539491 7.88885953396079,7.15224093497743 8.23463313526982

where you can see the ids 1,2,3, below to the first multipolygon, and 4,5 the other.

The general idea is you cluster the data, and then you intersect the returned clusters with the original data, using [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) to group the ids together, so that the returned Multipolygons now contain the original ids.  The use of [ST_CollectionExtract](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) with 3 as the second paramter, in conjunction with [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html), which splits the geometry collection returned by ST_ClusterIntersecting back into rows, returns each contiguous cluster as a (Multi)Polygon. The [ST_MakeValid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html) is because sometimes when you intersect geometries with other related geometries, such as the original polygons with your clustered polygonss, you get strange rounding effects and GEOS error about non-noded intersections and the like.

I answered a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233565/create-dissolved-buffer-from-multi-geometry-union-by-shared-attribute-and-spati/233682#233682) on gis.stackexchange recently that you might find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I'll try now on my dataset. I wasn't aware of the possibility to run ST_Intersect between the real geom and the clustered one. In this way should work!! :) great. Thank you again!